# SSRS parameter not populating

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am having SSRS report in which three parameter are present SBU,BU,MU. I am cascading them but the issue is when I select few values from the dropdown of Parameter BU , Parameter MU gets cascaded and only those values of MU comes which are under those selected BU, but now when I select all in BU, in the MU parameter in dropdown all the values comes but now also only those earlier MUs are selected and I explicitly have to select all in MU dropdown as well.
To get this issue resolved I saw this link
http://neerajsoft.blogspot.com/2012/07/multilevel-cascading-with-select-all.html
And for my SBU dataset I used the below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Selling_SBU
FROM T_SSRS_SECURITY
where UserId = @UserId AND (As_Database = 'CRP') and ([Selling_SBU] <> '') and ([Selling_SBU] is not null)
ORDER BY Selling_SBU ASC
```

For BU->

```
SELECT l11.Selling_BU1+'_'+ CAST(row_number() over( order by  l11.Selling_BU1 desc) AS VARCHAR(50) )as Selling_BU11
 ,l11.Selling_BU
FROM (
 SELECT l1.Selling_BU+'_'+ CAST(row_number() over( order by  l1.Selling_BU asc) AS VARCHAR(50) )as Selling_BU1
,l1.Selling_BU
                FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT Selling_BU
                                FROM T_SSRS_SECURITY
                                WHERE Selling_SBU IN (@Selling_SBU) and UserId = @UserId AND (As_Database = 'CRP') and ([Selling_BU] <> '') and ([Selling_BU] is not null)
                )l1
)l11
ORDER BY l11.Selling_BU ASC
```

For MU->

```
SELECT l11.Selling_MU1+'_'+ CAST(row_number() over( order by  l11.Selling_MU1 desc) AS VARCHAR(50) )as Selling_MU11
 ,l11.Selling_MU
FROM (
 SELECT l1.Selling_MU+'_'+ CAST(row_number() over( order by  l1.Selling_MU asc) AS VARCHAR(50) )as Selling_MU1
              ,l1.Selling_MU
                FROM (
                                SELECT DISTINCT Selling_MU
                                FROM T_SSRS_SECURITY
                                WHERE Selling_BU IN(@Selling_BU) and  UserId = @UserId AND (As_Database = 'CRP') and ([Selling_MU] <> '') and ([Selling_MU] is not null)
                                  )l1
  )l11
ORDER BY l11.Selling_MU ASC
```

But now the issue which I am getting is that my MU parameter is not getting populated. It's coming empty. Cascading is working perfectly between SBU and BU.

Comment: Are you really using SQL Server 2008? It's been unsupported for over 2 years now.

Comment: Did you set up the parameter to use the `.Label` and NOT the `.Value` that would usually be used? It's not pointed out in the article.

Comment: Yes that was the issue @HannoverFist . Thanks!!